# On some UNIX implementations, it is not possible to call free() on a block of memory allocated via memalign()

Tags: linux, posix, memory-management

I use Linux only but I want to understand what this means:

From *the Linux Programming Interface*:

> Blocks of memory allocated using `memalign()` or `posix_memalign()`
> should be deallocated with `free()`.
>
> On some UNIX implementations, it is not possible to call `free()` on a
> block of memory allocated via `memalign()`, because the `memalign()`
> implementation uses `malloc()` to allocate a block of memory, and then
> returns a pointer to an address with a suitable alignment in that
> block. The glibc implementation of `memalign()` doesn’t suffer this
> limitation.

From `man memalign`:

> POSIX  requires  that  memory  obtained from `posix_memalign()` can be
> freed using `free(3)`.  Some systems provide no way to reclaim memory
> allocated with
> `memalign()` or `valloc()` (because one can pass to `free(3)` only a pointer obtained from `malloc(3)`, while, for example,
> `memalign()` would call `malloc(3)` and
> then align the obtained value).  The glibc implementation allows memory obtained from any of these functions to be reclaimed
> with `free(3)`.

I don't know much about memory alignment and don't understand on "*for example, `memalign()` would call `malloc(3)` and then align the obtained value*".

Could someone tell me what's going on here and what could be wrong with `free()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `posix_memalign` should be used since it's defined by POSIX, as its name suggests. For issues with `memalign` see for example the [Solaris 10 manual page for memory allocation functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5168/memalign-3c.html):

> The argument to free() is a pointer to a block previously allocated by malloc(), calloc(), or realloc(). After free() is executed, this space is made available for further allocation by the application, though not returned to the system. Memory is returned to the system only upon termination of the application. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. If a random number is passed to free(), the results are undefined.

The description of `free()` doesn't even mention `memalign` allocations.

> for example, memalign() would call malloc(3) and then align the obtained value

The following implementation is an example of the given description:

```c
void *memalign(size_t alignment, size_t size)
{
    void *mem;
    uintptr_t uip_mem, uip_align;

    // fail if alignment is smaller than sizeof(void*) or not a power of two
    if (alignment < sizeof(void*) || alignment & (alignment - 1)) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    // allocate alignment extra bytes to prevent heap overflow
    mem = malloc(size + alignment);
    if (mem == NULL)
        return NULL;

    uip_mem = (uintptr_t) mem;
    uip_align = (uintptr_t) alignment;

    // align up returned address
    return (void*) ((uip_mem + uip_align - 1) & -uip_align);
}
```

See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Computing_padding) for more information about alignment. The previous implementation may or may not return the same address returned by `malloc`, depending on its alignment. Since the returned address may not be the exact same returned by a `malloc` call, it cannot safely be passed to `free`, as it expects an unchanged value returned by `malloc` (or other allocation function).

Comment: How *"The glibc implementation allows memory obtained from any of these functions to be reclaimed with `free(3)`"* ?